# Install Homebrew on Mojave get error Not a directory

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, macos-mojave

I try to install Homebrew on macOS Mojave, I ran this command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and I got this error

```
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
```

==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch

```
/tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
Password:****
touch: /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress: Not a directory
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
```

and one more thing I downloaded  Xcode Command Line Tools file and I tend to install on my macOS but I got failed messages from package installer.

Yours
Reza Dehnavi

Comment: did you try installing the command line tools first (`xcode-select --install`) and then installing homebrew?

Comment: Yes I did try that command, show me a dialog and I click to install but I got this error: “can’t download the software because of a network problem ”

Comment: @Lukas Unfortunately I have to reinstall macOS after that everything is OK.

Comment: I upgraded from Sierra to Mojave, and had a similar problem, ran xcode-select --install and got an Unknown network error trying to download the command line tools. Same thing over and over. Reinstalled Mojave, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by the firewall of macOS interfereing in Mojave with the updates process, it is not as other stated due to